# Hide userform and show a specified worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I load a UserForm, do some stuff, then want to hide that UserForm and show one of the open worksheets.  This worksheet has a command button to run a macro that will again show the UserForm.
What happens is that when I hide the UserForm, the ActiveSheet becomes the one which was active when the UserForm was loaded.  Subsequent attempts at defining the active sheet are ignored, with no error messages.

```
UserForm1.Show
' stuff
Workbooks("datafile").Sheets(1).Activate   ' ActiveSheet is correctly redefined
UserForm1.Hide   ' ActiveSheet changes to the active sheet when UserForm was loaded
Workbooks("datafile").Sheets(1).Activate      ' Ignored.  no change to ActiveSheet
' Shows whomever loaded the user form: either the VBA debugger or the original worksheet
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to recreate this issue, the posted code worked for me.

however, the `UserForm1` might be overlapping with the following instruction, try adding `DoEvents` function before activating the desired sheet again. something like this:

```
UserForm1.Show
' stuff
Workbooks("datafile").Sheets(1).Activate   ' ActiveSheet is correctly redefined
UserForm1.Hide   ' ActiveSheet changes to the active sheet when UserForm was loaded
DoEvents
Workbooks("datafile").Sheets(1).Activate
```

Answer (score 0):

It works out that a User Form is linked to the worksheet that was active when it was loaded.  Thus, if you want a particular sheet to be visible when you hide or minimize the form, make sure it was Active when you loaded that form.  It appears you cannot change ActiveSheets while a UserForm is loaded; you're stuck with the sheet that was there when the form was loaded.